# Image Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I did some research and found something very close to what I need (a very, very simple auto slideshow using images within an array). However, the code I found is not actually using images and I'm not quite sure how to alter the code so that it will work with an array of images instead of strings. I've only gotten as far as creating the array with images...

Any help would be very appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var wss_i = 0;
var wss_elem;
var wss_array = new Array;
wss_array[0] = "img0.png";
wss_array[1] = "img1.png";
wss_array[2] = "img2.png";
wss_array[3] = "img3.png";
wss_array[4] = "img4.png";
wss_array[5] = "img5.png";

function wssNext(){
wss_i++;
if(wss_i > (wss_array.length - 1)){
wss_i = 0;
}
setTimeout('wssSlide()',1000);
}

function wssSlide(){
wss_elem.innerHTML = wss_array[wss_i];
setTimeout('wssNext()',2000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My dog is <span id="wss"></span></h1>
<script>wss_elem = document.getElementById("wss");
wssSlide();
</script>
</body>    </html>
```

Comment: If that's the code you found in your research, do more research - it's horrid code!

Comment: I'm open to suggestions! I'm really new at coding JavaScript and am just looking for the simplest possible way to create a slideshow with an image array. This was the most fitting code I've come across. :/

Comment: It has two^wthree _very_ newbie errors in it - 1. wss_array[n] over and over instead of a simple `var wss_array = [ list of elements ]`, and 2. passing strings to `setTimeout`, 3. massive pollution wuth global variables

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your `<span>` with an `<img>` element, your code might then look like:

```
(function() {                       // anonymous function expression - no globals!

    // following declarations are local to the function
    var wss = document.getElementById("wss");
    var imgs = [ "img0.png", "img1.png", ... ];
    var n = 0;

    (function next() {
        wss.src = imgs[n];          // set the image's src
        n = (n + 1) % imgs.length;  // increment the counter
        setTimeout(next, 2000);     // and queue up the next change
    })();                           // invoke immediately so the first image loads

})();                               // start it all up
```

and that's it!

Put this entire code in your `<script>` tag at the very end of your `<body>` element to ensure that the DOM is loaded before the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert an `<img>` tag that will be used to display the images:

```
<span id="wss"><img id="my_img" src="img0.png" /></span>
```

and then change its `src` property to the next image:

```
function wssSlide() {
    var img = document.getElementById('my_img');
    img.src = wss_array[wss_i];
    window.setTimeout(wssNext, 2000);
}
```

Comment: this is really not a good solution - there should be a single static image element whose `src` gets changed using DOM properties!

Comment: Good point. I will update my answer to take your suggestion into account.